# How to remove space after hiding the xml elements in web view

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am developing android application and have no knowledge about css and javascript. I need to show a webpage in my webview, but with few of its elements hidden. My following code is working successfully

```
 @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);

      try {
          view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                  "document.getElementById('header').style.visibility='collapse';})()");
        /*  view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                  "document.getElementById('header').style.visibility='hidden';})()");*/
      }catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

"header" is the id of the header, and it is getting hidden, but the space that it originally occupied on the top remains.So how to hide that space.

Thanks  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display:none` to hide the element completely and set `display:block` to show it again.

Or in your case `.style.display='none';`

If you set display:none, it hides the entire element, while visibility:hidden means that the contents of the element will be invisible, but the element stays in its original position and size.

Comment: I don't want to show it, I used display: none, still some space remains. How to position the bottom element to top ? after I have hidden it ?

Comment: @Pritish display none will completely hide the element and it space, if there is still some space that you want to hide it's probably that there is still an element that takes space around the header like a <div> or someting

Comment: "_I used display: none, still some space remains_" Not possible, in that case it has been some other element taking space, `display:none` removes the element totally from the textflow, unless you're using IE<8.

Comment: @mrdeadsven  yes, the space belongs to the bottom element, so basically there is some space between the header and the bottom title, so what can be done to move the bottom title at top ?

Comment: @Pritish find the element that is taking in the space that you want removed and also give it a display:none. This way it will also be completely hidden.

Comment: Actually on laptop that space is not visible, but on mobile it is, so need to find out how it is occurring with bootstrap, all this website stuff is latin and greek to me,need some time to find out :) :) anyways thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Pritish No problem, if you add your html code that you are using to your question and point out what is still taking in space (with an image) we might be able to completely solve the problem. Otherwise good luck!

Answer (score 1):

try `document.getElementById('header').style.display='none'`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Jsoup:

You can remove tag or id like this:

```
public void removeUnusedHTMLTags(org.jsoup.nodes.Document document, String tagClassOrId) {
    Elements categories = document.select(tagClassOrId);
    for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element element : categories){
        Log.v(">>>", "Remove unused tag " + tagClassOrId);
        element.remove();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You need to add Jsoup library:

```
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
```

To get document:

```
Connection con = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .ignoreContentType(true);
Connection.Response res = con.execute();
String rawJSON = res.body();
Document document = Jsoup.parse(rawJSON);
```

Comment: Do you know any plugin, as the object Elements is not available by default in android studio

Comment: You can get document from url with the code above. Remember to do it in another thread